# Linker errors after adding Flurry library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, flurry

I created a new app from scratch to test with Flurry.

After following their documentation, downloading the SDK and adding it to the app I'm getting the following error messages: [image]

I've linked the all the frameworks they require: [image]

I have architectures set to standard with armv7 and arm64 and running `lipo -info` on the `libFlurry_7.6.0.a` and `libFlurryAds_7.6.0.a` files shows that they both support architectures: i386, armv7, x86_64, and arm64.

I'm trying to build to the iOS simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the libraries in your project root?

If `yes` skip to step 2. If `no` add it:

**Step 1**

[image]

**Step 2:** Go to Target > Build Settings > Search Paths > Library Search Paths > add: `$(inherited)` and `$(SRCROOT)` and `$(PROJECT_DIR)`
[image]

You don't need the 3 search paths, but just to make sure it will look for into your project. I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ended up removing all references to Flurry and all the files related to it. Then re-adding the Flurry folder to root and the linker references were automatically generated. It may also matter that I didn't re-add the FlurryAds library as I won't be needing it. My library search paths was full of a lot of paths so I removed most of them too. After all that it started working. So I'm not sure exactly what was breaking but your answer definitely helped, thanks!

Comment: That's great! I upvoted your question, maybe it can help someone in future.